# Gradle library version suggestion when using variables

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I use variables to set the version for multiple libraries in my gradle file.
Problem is, once I use a variable, I don't get suggestions when an upgrade is available.

For example:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        supportLibVersion = '27.0.0'
        ...
    }
    ...
```

and in the module file -

```
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The latest version for the support library is about 27.1.1. If I set the version 27.0.0 directly to one of the implementations, I get a recommendation to upgrade it, but if I use a variable, I don't.

Is there a way to both set a variable for all the implementations and get a recommendation?

Comment: @InsaneCat I added the android-studio tag on purpose, this question (unlike many others) really has to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set the variable in `allprojects` block instead of `buildscript`.

Comment: is it fine to have same dependency in different versions: `implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibVersion}"`

Comment: @Blasanka You mean the `v4` and `v13`? That's not a library version, but rather Googles somewhat confusing way of naming the support library.

Comment: Tried doing that, gradle doesn't sync now. the variable isn't recognized

Comment: Do you have the dependencies in `buildscript` as well? They don't belong there. They should go in the app module build.gradle file.

Comment: @Henry I have a variable for the Kotlin version along with a dependency for it in both the buildscript and the the app module build.gradle (different ones). They have to be there, along with several other plugins.

Comment: @Henry Okay but it doesn't work with something like this: ```rxJavaVersion = '2.2.2'``` and then ```rxJava:"io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"``` . Do you have any solution for that? Thanks.